# creating link for grails view from javascript

Tags: javascript, grails, href

I have a table with one column redirecting to another page. But table changes dynamically so I need to create the link in javascript function.

I am trying to create link a href=""  which call another view with parameters.
I need below createrlink into my href but when I insert it ..it just ignoring the parameter part

````
 linkpage = '${createLink(action:'showGraph')}?inputprscode='+ phenocatsel+'&inprscat='+phenocatsel+'&inprsstudy='+phenomesel;


linkpage =  '<a class="intro"  href="<g:createLink action="showGraph" params="${[inputprscode:phecode, inprscat: prssrc ,inprsstudy:phenomes]}"/>">link</a></li>';```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I created url  as string and then just inserted into the a href to solve the quote problem

`linkpagedr = '${createLink(action:'showGraph')}?inputprscode='+ phenocatsel+'&inprscat='+phenocatsel+'&inprsstudy='+phenomesel;`
`linkpage ='<a class="intro" href="'+linkpagedr +'">link</a>';`

But I m not sure if this is an efficient way. If anybody knows a better way to implement this , please let me know.